# GET request with AFNetworking 3.0 in Objective-c

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, afnetworking-3

I'm working to create an app for iOS based on an windows old one. So, in the login of the app I need to connect to a web service passing the user, pass and app_version. I'm getting a 400, so I'm failing somewhere. Here's my code:

```
static NSString *const BASE_URL = @"my://url";

static NSString *const SUBDIRECTORY = @"/api/v1";

static NSString *const API_NAME = @"Basic";

static NSString *const API_KEY = @"mykey";

- (void)logUserWithName:(NSString *)user
           password:(NSString *)password
       successBlock:(void(^)(void)) successBlock
          failBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error)) failBlock {

    NSDictionary *body = @{@"user" : user,
                       @"pass" : password,
                       @"app_version" : @"1.0"
                       };
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSString *auth = [[API_NAME stringByAppendingString:@" "] stringByAppendingString:API_KEY];
    NSString *URL = [[BASE_URL stringByAppendingString:SUBDIRECTORY] stringByAppendingString:@"/auth"];
    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];
    NSMutableURLRequest * req = [[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:URL parameters:nil error:nil];
    [req setValue:auth forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    [req setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    req.timeoutInterval = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"timeoutInterval"] longValue];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [[manager dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSLog(@"Reply JSON: %@", responseObject);
            successBlock();
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@, %@", error, response, responseObject);
            failBlock(error);
       }
   }] resume];
}
```

And here I have the same operation implemented in the windows app, which is working:

```
    private const String BASE_URL = @"my://url";

    private const String SUBDIRECTORY = "/api/v1";

    private static String API_NAME = "Basic";
    //private static String API_KEY = "exampleAPI_KEY";
    private static String API_KEY = "mykey";

    private static String AUTH = API_NAME + " " + API_KEY;

    private const String NETWORK_ERROR = "Network error";

    private const String ERROR = "Error ";

    // all operation returns error_code and error_message

    //returns an array[] de un elemento{} user_token
    public static async Task<UserToken> Login(string User, string Pass, string App_version)
    {
        var Client = new RestClient(new Uri(BASE_URL));
        Client.IgnoreResponseStatusCode = true;
        var Request = new RestRequest(SUBDIRECTORY + "/auth", Method.GET);
        Request.AddHeader("Authorization", AUTH);
        Request.AddParameter("Content-type", "application/json", ParameterType.HttpHeader);
        Request.AddParameter("user", User, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        Request.AddParameter("pass", Pass, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        Request.AddParameter("app_version", App_version, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
        var Response = await Client.Execute<UserToken>(Request);
        var ResponseData = Response.Data;
        if (Response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            return ResponseData;
        }
```

Comment: `[req setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];` => `[req setHTTPBody:jsonData]];` Because you are doing `NSData` to `NSString` to `NSData`. That's useless. But usually on a GET method there is not `HTTPBody`. It should be on the URL (while sending them in the clear in the URL is quite strange).

Comment: @Larme How should it be then? I'm not sure of how to add it on the URL.

Comment: Could you check the URL used on the Windows? And give us the value (you can hide sensitive data on it) Could work on using `[[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:URL parameters:body error:nil];`

Comment: I wasn't adding the body, totally true... But it still doesn't work, the url is the same in both systems but I'm adding the SUBDIRECTORY and the "/auth" in a way that I don't know if it's correct. What do you think about it?

Comment: @Larme ok passing the body as a parameter like you say works. It was failing beacuse I didn't remove it from the request http body (my fault). So if you post it as an answer I'll give it to you

Comment: So if you do NSLog(@"FinalRequest: %@", [[req URL] absoluteString]);, you are sending the userName/password in clear?

Comment: Yeah, it goes as a parameter in the URL like my://url/api/v1/auth?app_version=1&pass=312&user=123

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 NSString *urlAsString = @"http://------------";

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];

 NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest   requestWithURL:url];
 [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:30.0f];
 [urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

 NSString *body =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"apiKey=%@&platform=%@",@"param1",@"param2"];

 [urlRequest setHTTPBody:[body   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
 [NSURLConnection
  sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
  queue:queue
  completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                 NSData *data,
                 NSError *error) {
   if ([data length] >0 && error == nil){

     NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];




     NSLog(@"getConfig respo is : %@",responseDict);

     if(responseDict!=nil)
     {

         if([[responseDict valueForKey:@"Status"] integerValue] == 200)
         {
             NSLog(@"getConfig success");



         }

         else
         {




         }

     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"getConfig nil Dic ");
     }

 }
 else
 {
     NSLog(@"getConfig error : %@",error);


 }

 }];


 }
```

Comment: Neither... What do you think about the way I create the request?